# What is the point of streamwriters having Close() and Dispose()?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-c++, com

When you call `Close` on an active `StreamWriter` it makes it impossible to write any more code to the stream (since it's been closed). To open another stream, you have to make a new instance of a `StreamWriter` since there's no 'Open' method.

My question is, what's the point in having `Close` and `Dispose` when you can't really use anything besides `Dispose` after closing the stream?

I could understand if there was an `Open` function, i.e. you could close one file then open another using the same `StreamWriter`. But as there is only `Close` and you can't really use anything besides `Dispose` afterwards, why not just get rid of `Close` and have `Dispose` close the underlying stream as its first action?

I get that `Dispose` comes from `IDisposeable` and all that.  What I want to know is why `Close` is needed specifically when `Dispose` appears to call `Close` anyway.

As far as I can see, without the ability to open another stream with the same `StreamWriter`, there is no point in having `Close` when you have no option but to `Dispose` afterwards since all other methods become useless.

Why is is that `StreamWriter` bothers having `Close` when they could merge `Close` and `Dispose` into a single method?

Comment: It looks like you have it backwards - `Close` calls `Dispose`, not the other way around.

Comment: `Close` calls `Dispose`, which closes the underlying stream resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with streams there's a long standing convention that `Close` is a method that they have to close the stream.  It's terminology that many programmers are used to and expect to see when dealing with streams.  It would have been potentially confusing to have a stream without a `Close` method, and may have taken some time for people to realize that they should use `Dispose` to close the stream.

It's certainly *possible* for the class to have implemented `IDisposable` explicitly, so that the `Dispose` method wouldn't be there without a cast to `IDisposable`, and that my have cleaned up some of the confusion, but they choose not to do that and to leave two duplicate methods in the class.

It's entirely up to your personal preference whether you use `Dispose` or `Close` to close the stream.

Comment: I've read this many times, that close is part of streams and reader/writers simply because of the convention of "closing" a file.  I can't remember, but I feel like that tidbit of information was outlined in CLR via C#.

Comment: `Close` is really just a friendlier-named remnant from .NET 1.0, before they had their conventions down. Microsoft has since said that `Dispose` should be preferred for consistency across various APIs, and hasn't written a feature-duplicating `Close` method since.

Comment: Going back over some of my past questions that didn't have an answer. I've picked this one since all the other answers seemed to be addressing my mix up between whether `Close` calls `Dispose` or the other way around rather than my actual question of "Why is is that StreamWriter bothers having Close when they could merge Close and Dispose into a single method?". I don't know for definite if this is *the* correct answer, but it's certainly the *most correct* out of the answers presented.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx), `Close` just calls `Dispose` with a value of `true`.

> - This method overrides Close.
> - This implementation of Close calls the
>     Dispose method passing a true value.
> - You must call Close to ensure
>     that all data is correctly written out to the underlying stream.
>     Following a call to Close, any operations on the StreamWriter might
>     raise exceptions. If there is insufficient space on the disk, calling
>     Close will raise an exception.

`Dispose` itself is inherited from [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), which is used by classes that have resources that need to be released.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a stream allocates both application and system resources. If your application opens many streams without closing them, then it restricts the ability of other applications to access those files. It's important that streams are closed as soon as possible.

As far as why streams don't have the ability to reopen, this is basically the .NET approach. The class represents an open stream. So create one to access the stream and get rid of it as soon as possible. When you want to access the stream again, you create another one.

I think it would be valid to create a stream class that could be reopened, but it does cause some problems as many of the methods wouldn't work when the stream was closed. In the end, a stream class really does represent an *open* stream.

`Dispose` is just there to make it easier to ensure the stream gets cleaned up in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

> why not just get rid of close and have dispose close the underlying stream as its first action?

It's good programming practice.

Suppose you have lights in your house that turn off automatically when you leave.  You wouldn't *have* to turn  off the lights when you left, but it's good *practice*.  That way, you wouldn't require that every house you live in to automatically turn off the lights.  You'd be in the habit of turning them off yourself.

Explicitly calling `Close()` tells the reader (and the system) "I'm done with this stream", and calling `Dispose()` tells the system (and the reader) "you can release any embedded resources".

Comment: There is no need to call both methods.  `Close` just calls `Dispose`.  Calling both is just redundant, and by no means a good practice.

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track when you say "why not just get rid of..." except it's backwards.  If you look at the underlying code for `StreamWriter.Close()` you will see:

```
public override void Close()
{
  this.Dispose(true);
  GC.SuppressFinalize((object) this);
}
```

So the Close() method is just the way you would tell the framework that you are done writing to the stream.